# How bash inverse pattern matching works internally in extglob?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob, extglob

Below files are present in current directory.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 kazama kazama 0 Feb 16 08:50 london_july_2001_001.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kazama kazama 0 Feb 16 08:50 london_march_2004_002.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 kazama kazama 0 Feb 16 08:50 newyork_dec_2012_005.jpeg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kazama kazama 0 Feb 16 08:50 paris_sept_2007_003.jpg
```

I want to filter all images except which starts with "paris" text.

I have tried below command which works as per my expectation.

```
ls -l !(paris*)
```

But, I do not understand why below 2 commands do not give me expected output. In both of the cases it shows all the 4 files.

`ls -l !(paris)*.*(jpeg|jpg|png)`

`ls -l !(paris)*`

How bash interprets this extended globbing syntax internally ?Is it first trying to match !(paris)  then it tries to match (jpeg|jpg|png) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!(paris)` matches anything but `paris`, which includes `paris_`, `pari`, `par`, `pa`, `p`, and even the empty string. Bash will find something that doesn't match `paris` and try to match the rest of the pathname against the rest of the pattern. See:

```
$ echo !(paris)london*
london_july_2001_001.jpeg london_march_2004_002.png
$ echo !(paris)_*
london_july_2001_001.jpeg london_march_2004_002.png newyork_dec_2012_005.jpeg paris_sept_2007_003.jpg
$ echo !(paris)_*_*_*
london_july_2001_001.jpeg london_march_2004_002.png newyork_dec_2012_005.jpeg
```

Comment: When `!(paris)` matches anything but `paris` shouldn't it discard the file which starts with `paris` & then give the result ?How come `paris` is still coming in the output ?

Comment: @Sking no, `!(paris)*` is no different from `*`. It'll match `paris_sept_2007_003.jpg` too because `!(paris)` matches `p`, `pa`, `par`, `pari`, `paris_`, etc. anything but `paris`, and `*` matches the rest.

Comment: now I understand why above code do not work. Your above answer absolutely makes sense that `!(paris)*` is no different from `*`.Hence, even with `!(paris)*` as well because of last `*` it effectively matches all the file name present in that path. Thank you for your explanation.